# SyntaxError: Unexpected token const { in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a new Bie to node.js. I am getting Syntax Error:

> Unexpected token { in my  node.js application

I am using v4.5.5 on windows 7 64 bit os.

```
  const {
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Let me know how to get rid of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's absolutely no way to tell.

Comment: Why do you have a `{` after [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)?

Comment: reinstall node https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Too much hostility and downvotes to a totally legit question here. @MarcB, your link to the "FM" is useless as this way to declare a constant is not present. The synthax is correct, as it's said in the answers, is just a node version issue. So, go FTFM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue got fixed by upgrading node js  to `v6.3.1` .
After upgrading to `6.3.1` ,I got another error related to isomorphoc-fetch that I fixed it by using `npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise`

`Ref Link:` https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch.

Thanks all  for your inputs

Comment: The node version I am using is *6.11.3*, but still, the issue persists. Can anyone please help?

Comment: hi Andy can you please raise a separate question since the version what I specified and what you are specifying is different.There might be some changes in 6.11.3.Also mention the issue your facing.

Comment: Ok Pradeep. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

From your code `const { name, age } = user;` seems like you try using object destruction in Node v4 it's available in Node v6.

If it's not possible to switch to v6 you have to refactor the destruct statements into classical object property access(`const name = user.name; const age = user.age`). Also, you could transpile the code with babel.

Answer (score 5):

You must probably set harmony destructuring flag like, (if you are using less than Node version 6)

```
node --harmony-destructuring app.js
```